# Distance between two disjoint sets $K$ and $F$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Suppose $K$ and $F$ are disjoint in a metric space $X$, $K$ is compact, $F$ is closed. Prove that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $d(p,q)>\delta$ if $p\in K, q\in F$. *Hint:* $\rho_F$ is a continuous positive function on $K$.
>
> Show that the conclusion may fail for two disjoint closed sets if neither is compact.

Here, $$\rho_E(x):=\inf_{z\in E}d(x,z).$$

And we know that $$\rho_E(x)=0\iff x\in \overline{E}.$$

**My attempt:**

$\rho_F(p)>0$ for all $p\in K$ since $K\cap F=\varnothing$ and $F=\overline{F}$ $(\rho_F(p)=0\iff p\in \overline{F}).$

So we have $$d(p,q)>0,\ p\in K,\ q\in F.$$

Following the hint, $\rho_F(K)$ is compact (since $\rho_F$ is a continuous mapping).

Thus it is closed, and $0\not\in \rho_F(K)\implies 0$ is not a limit point.

$\implies\exists \delta>0$ such that $\rho_F(p)>\delta,\ p\in K.$

$\implies d(p,q)>\delta.$

If neither is compact, we can't be sure whether $\rho_F(K)$ is closed or not (since we don't know whether $\rho_F$ is an open mapping or not).

In fact, let $A=(0,1)$ then $\rho_A(A)=\{0\}$; it maps an open set into a closed set. Therefore it is not an open mapping.

A specific counterexample for the problem is $K=\{(x,y):y=0\},\ F=\{(x,y):y=1/x\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Both $K$ and $F$ are closed but not bounded, so not compact. And the distance between them is getting closer as $x\to \infty.$ (more specifically, for any $\delta>0$, we can always find $x$ such that $d((x,0),(x,1/x))=1/x < \delta$.)

---

Is my attempt correct?

Answer (score 1):

$\rho_F$ is a continuous function on a compact and is positive. Therefore it achieves its minimum, necessarily positive on $K$.

Your counter example is correct but a simpler one would be $\{0\}$ and $(0,1)$ on the real line.

Comment: Error: \rho = $\rho$

Comment: But aren't they compact and open?

Comment: And I guess $\rho_{(0,1)}(\{0\})=\{0\}$

Comment: $\{0\}$ is compact in $R$ and $(0,1)$ is open hence not compact ( compact subsets are closed) An example where none of them is compact is $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(-1,0)$. The distance between them is clearly zero as well.

Comment: $\pho$ is a nonnegative real number equal to zero, not $\{0\}$. The latter would be a set. Not getting the Greek letters compiled by Latex for some reason..

Comment: No, they should be closed

Comment: I see. Then your example is perfect since they should be unbounded